# One-tailed Mann-Whitney U-test by hand - which U-stat vs order for treatments on critical values table

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am comparing a certain activity in an animal using a one-tailed Mann-Whitney U-test.

I would like to know if the activity increases from treatment A to treatment B.
Alternatively, I could look at whether it decreases from treatment B to treatment A (if that works better for the test), since it's the same thing.

However, how would I know which way round to put the treatments when using the one-tailed critical values tables?

(My actual values are slightly different, but...)
If, for example, treatment A used n= 5 and treatment B n=8, the one tailed test tables have critical values one way round for n1=5 and  n2=8, but there is just a blank space the other way round, for n2=5 and n1=8.

I have two U values, Ua was 1.5 and Ub was 16.5, do I just use the lower one, and assume that n1 =5 and n2=8 so resulting in a critical value of 8 (for p <0.05) or would I need to follow a particular order with n1 and n2 being for treatment A and B depending on which U stat I use.

So far I haven't been able to find any clear worked examples (by hand) of one-tailed tests via google.

Thank you for any help!!